# how to retrieve other data fields based on the dropdownlist selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have displayed a column of data in dropdownlist and then I have assigned a String the selected value of dropdownlist.Based on the selected value of the dropdownlist I need to retrieve other data fields of that row .
for instance I have selected a name of the employee from the dropdownlist and now I have to display the id and salary of that employee in separate texboxes how do I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you mean the DropdownList from WebForms then it will have a DataTextField and a DataValueField. You can set the DataValueField to the id and do a database lookup for the rest. This old tech will have tons of info online

Comment: The method is different for 'ASP.Net Web Forms' and 'ASP.Net MVC'. So tell me which type of application you are using?

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, we need more information here. Since you are new, then I suppose we can let this poor information slide here. However, the MOST important aspect of software is not actually writing code. it is in fact how you lay out the problem and question.

So, assuming web forms, and a drop down list?

Unlike desktop, you can assign a list of objects, or even a WHOLE data row to a drop down, and upon selection you can return/get that whole data row.

However, for web based dropdown? They don't store/save/remember the WHOLE DATA row object, but only retain two columns.

You thus have the ability to save/store TWO columns in the drop down.

The one column is hidden - that is a the value column. Typical, we use that to store/save the data base row PK (primary key) value. But, you are allowed a 2nd column for display of information.

Upon seletion of the drop down, then you can get htat text value, or you can get the hidden datbase row PK id.

So, say we have this simple drop down to select a hotel name.

```
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Hotel" Font-Size="Large">
        </asp:Label>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
            style="margin-left:10px" Width="150px"
            DataValueField = "ID"
            DataTextField = "HotelName"
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
```

And the code to fill is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCombo();
    }


    void LoadCombo()
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL 
            = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        DropDownList1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        // add extra please select option to drop down
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Hotel", "0"));
    }
```

And now we get this:

[image]

And our code behind when we select a hotel, can be this:

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value != "0")
        {
            // user selected a hotel, get all hotel information

            SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
                new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID");
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
            DataRow rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL).Rows[0];

            txtHotel.Text = rstData["HotelName"].ToString();
            tFN.Text = rstData["FirstName"].ToString() ;
            tLN.Text = rstData["LastName"].ToString() ;
            tCity.Text = rstData["City"].ToString() ;
            tProvince.Text = rstData["Province"].ToString();
            chkActive.Checked = (bool)rstData["Active"];
            chkBalcony.Checked = (bool)rstData["Balcony"];
            txtNotes.Text = rstData["Description"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

So, assuming we drop some text boxes below the drop down list, say like this:

```
 <div id="EditRecord" runat="server" style="float:left;display: normal;border:solid 2px;padding:5px">

        <style>
            .iForm label {display:inline-block;width:90px}
            .iForm input {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px}                
            .iForm textarea {border-radius:8px;border-width:1px;margin-bottom:10px}     
            .iForm input[type=checkbox] {margin-right:8px}
        </style>


        <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
                <label>HotelName</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"  width="280" />  <br />
                <label>First Name</label> <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>Last Name</label>  <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server"  Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>City</label> <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server"  Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>Province</label>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server"  Width="75"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px" class="iForm">
            <label>Description</label> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="400" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                Height="150px" f="Description" ></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" f="Active" Text=" Active" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" f="Balcony" Text=" Has Balcony" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn" style="margin-left:10px" />
   </div>
```

We now have this:

[image]

So, we get the PK row database "ID" from the drop down, and then we can pull the whole database row, and get all the information about that one row we want, and can do whatever we like  -- such as per above display that selected information on the web page.

The other routine I used (became super tired of typing code over and over to pull data), so I have this helper routine:

```
    public  DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```